# Android v. IPad Programming

Tags: java, android, c++, ipad

IPad APP development

I have been programming for more than 35 years, more than 20 in C++
I developed an APP to use on my Android Phone (in Eclipse)
It was very easy to learn Java because of my C++ experience
My wife wants to use this APP on her IPad
I do NOT want to distribute the APP in the Apple App Store, ONLY for personal use

It is very EASY to use my PC and Eclipse to write a Java program then use my Phone to DEBUG

1) Can I do this in a similar way on her IPad?
(I don’t have a Mac)
2) Is there a quick Tutorial showing the differences between the Android world and the Apple world?

Comment: There are "kind" of ways you can do this without a Mac, it's not easy, as you need a Mac to do the final compiling and many of the tools are only available on the Mac. You can build apps and distribute the, to testers u via the TestFlight website, it's not exactly the same, but it will get the job done.

Comment: If you want  simpler developer approach, you could look at Project CodeName One, which is a Java based API which is capable of been compiled to native iOS, Android and Windows Phone (and Blackberry I believe), it means you can get a app using a single code branch, and compile it to your target platform

Comment: You can write a swing application and convert it to a web based application using Ajax Swing, although it is bound to run very slowly as compared to a native application.